# What Methods Are Used to Generate and Transfer Power to the Stargate?

Tags: stargate

Related to questions:

- [DHD Connection to
  Stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32832/is-a-dial-home-device-connected-to-a-stargate-in-a-wired-or-wireless-fashion)
- [Stargate Power Requirements (Sci-Fi Exchange)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39476/how-much-power-does-it-take-to-establish-a-wormhole-in-the-stargate-franchise)
- [Black Hole Powering Stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/how-can-a-stargate-draw-power-from-a-black-hole)
- [Stargate Power Requirements (Forum)](http://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/the-stargate-and-power-requirements.75810/)

I could probably answer this on my own, but I know there are much better people that can explain the answer to this question in more detail than I can manage.

I realize one of the related questions I listed is a method (if unorthodox) of powering a gate, however, for this question, the answers I am expecting to find concentrate on typical gate power sources and not specialized gates such as the Ori Supergate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asker's Answer:

> **NOTE:**
>
> It seems that two processes are required to establish a successful
>   connection:
>
> - Dialing in and locking the addresses with the correlating chevrons
> - Creating a stable wormhole from the source gate to the destination gate
>
> This answer attempts to explain the 2<sup>nd</sup> requirement, since the 1<sup>st</sup>
>   is relatively easy.

**Typical Stargates: *Ground Based***

For typical, ground based stargates within the Milky Way gate system, as well as the Pegauses and (Universe)/Destiny/Seedship system, power is supplied by the DHD's Cold Fusion Reactor Core<sup>[1](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Cold_fusion_reactor_core)</sup>, which also powers the DHD itself. While not explained directly in cannon, power is likely transferred from the DHD's power source wirelessly<sup>[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_energy_transfer)</sup> through either microwave radiation, or more likely induction, since both the DHD and the stargate are made of the superconductive Naquahdah<sup>[3](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Naquadah)</sup>.

**Typical Stargates: *"Space Gates"***

Gates that are fixed within the vacuum of space (space gates), most typically found in the Pegauses gate system, possess attached power nodes<sup>[4](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_power_node)</sup>, which are affixed along the outer edge of gate. While the method of power is not exactly known, most likely the power source of each node is a modified version of the Cold Fusion Reactor Core, with the addition of electrical RCS stabilizers.

**Non-Typical Stargates**

For atypical cases, in which a DHD is absent or damaged, power can come from a number of sources, though in some cases those sources may have undesirable behaviors:

*Direct Methods*

- *Static Electricity* via lightning (SG-1, Torment of Tantalus)
- *Current Electricity* via heavy-gauge conduit (Stargate @ Stargate Command (SG-1)); via jumper cable (SG-1, 1969)
- *High Energy Electromagnetic Radiation* via energy weapons fire (Atlantis, First Strike)

*Indirect Methods*

- *Extreme Gravitational Fields* via black hole (SG-1, A Matter of Time)

static and current electricity, high energy electromagnetic radiation (e.g., microwave, infrared (heat), x-ray and gamma-ray), and even indirectly from strong gravitational fields.

Comment: I doubt the gate uses that power source to form wormholes, however. Remember that when dialing manually, the gate only requires a small jolt of electricity to engage chevrons. Once the point-of-origin symbol is locked, the gate activates without any additional energy input. Probably some form of subspace, dimensional, or zero-point energy is used to create wormholes.

Comment: Stargates are known to accept power from many different sources. It is canonical that DHD's do contain power sources, but I cannot recall of any episode where a separate power source is mentioned to actually open the wormhole. Edited the related links to include power related info.

Comment: The gate in SG-1 episode "Prisoners" does not have a DHD, but SG-1 still successfully dials it manually by only providing charges from their organic cold fusion circuit to engage chevrons. I suppose you could argue that the cold fusion provides the power for the wormhole as well, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @called2voyage Hell, the SGC doesn't have a DHD!

Comment: The gate at the SGC has an electrical room that supplies power to the gate. I wouldn't call it a typical setup. I should probably ask the question; how much power does it take to create a wormhole, and refine the answer to this question so it covers more.

Answer (score -2):

You only need to connect the gate to the other, because there is a safety feature when the power is interrupted from sending the gate. The receiving gate will supply power to both gates.

Comment: Though true, this assumes the presence of an active, powered gate to sustain the (de-powered) sending gate. The question asks how a gate _becomes_ powered in the first place.